# Where in or contains query optimization

Tags: sql-server, linq

i am trying to optimize a query which is using contains clause in linq to entities , below is scenario

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities AWEntities = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    int?[] productModelIds = {19, 26, 118};
    var products = from p in AWEntities.PrdTransacation
                   where productModelIds.Contains(p.ProductModelID)
                   select p;
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", product.ProductModelID, product.ProductID);
    }
}
```

i exactly have similar kind of query but with productModelIds containing 2000 entries and PrdTransacation contains 5 million rows.

I have read over stackoverflow where people are recomending that contains should not have more then a dozen parameter. But apart from that any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend that.

The use of `Contains` it's translated in a `IN` clause. So if you have a look at the "Remarks" section of this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) you can see that Microsoft suggest to load the values in a table.

Of course this is not your case. From the code I assume you are using Entity Framework, and assuming you are using SQL Sever, I suggest you to create a *Table-Valued User-Defined* function and pass the list of your IDs.

I would use your approach *only for few items*.